# Using HTML Entities within AngularJS strings

Tags: javascript, string, angularjs

Given a string in my $scope model which contains an HTML entity, how do I ensure that the entity is properly displayed as an HTML character rather than a literal string?

[HTML entity - MDN Glossary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)

http://plnkr.co/edit/0BliljcDkj0vvj3jdEqz?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" 
            data-semver="1.2.13" 
            src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="htmlChar">{{title}}</div>

    <script>

      angular.element(document).ready(function(){

        var app=angular.module("app",[]);
        app.controller("htmlChar",function($scope){
          $scope.title = "&copy; Acme";
        });
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);

      });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A character entity, &copy; for example.   http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With [$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce). You need to explicitely tell angular the content is html.

```
<div ng-controller="htmlChar" ng-bind-html="title"></div>

<script>

  angular.element(document).ready(function(){

    var app=angular.module("app",[]);
    app.controller("htmlChar",function($scope, $sce){
      $scope.title = $sce.trustAsHtml("&copy; Acme");
    });
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);

  });

</script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9iNnRC7AxFptnQZLPtYR?p=preview

Comment: and he must use ng-bind-html

Comment: and for ng-bind-html to work you need angular-sanitize too

Answer (score 16):

You *do not* need `$sce` to bind to strings with html.  All you need is to inject `ngSanitize` into your app (it is not a core module), and then use the `ng-bind-html` attribute directive.

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = '&#189; Cookies &amp; <span class="cream">Cream</span>';
});
```

**Html**

```
<div ng-bind-html="title"></div>
```

## [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qRmD8h9B9DcctHk5Ovyl?p=preview)