# Rendering html numbers and escaped characters with angular js

Tags: json, angularjs, htmlspecialchars

i'm using an ng-repeat directive to show a list of posts,
retrieved through a wordpress-json-api.

i have problems with some characters, as the output of wp-json-api escapes some of them.

myjson :

```
 {
 "id": 1,
 "type": "mynicetype",
 "slug": "myniceslug",
 "title": "It&#8217;s a strange char" //my apostrophe got changed
 ... }
```

and my markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in menu.posts | filter:searchText | filter:query" >
   <h4 >name : {{post.title}}</h4>
</li>
```

get rendered (obviously-awfully) as

```
name : It&#8217;s a strange char
```

What's the best approach for formatting these html numbers? (before assigning the json.success data to the scope or, more easily, on the fly, inside template? but how?)

(btw i don't get the reason why an apostrophe should receive a special treatment by a json-api, but i could really be misunderstanding something here)

Thanks for any clarification

Comment: It's  two part solution look for `ng-bind-html` and `$sce`

Comment: the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919533/using-html-entities-within-angular-strings

Comment: possible duplicate of [With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)

Comment: thanks for pointing to right resource (i finished using Alex's solution there, as i was not able to use accepted solution.. still have a lot of things to learn about angularjs). but rocks!