# How to return the $http true function value to filter function

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and i just want to return value of $http service to filter function so following is code....

```
.filter('mapMedicine', function($http) {
          return function(input) {
            if (!input){
              return '';
            } else {
                return $http.get('/rest-apis/medicines/'+input).then(function(response){
                    return response.data.name;
                });
            }
          };
    })
```

above function returns {} How to make that work?
and I am Using filter in uiGrid cellDropDown like

```
$scope.bindGrid1={
                enablePagination:false,
                enableFiltering: true,
                useExternalSorting: true,
                enablePaginationControls: false,
                columnDefs: [
                             {field: 'medicine', displayName: 'Medicine/Test', width: '20%',
                                 cellFilter:"mapMedicine",
                                 editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
                                 editDropdownIdLabel: 'id',
                                 editDropdownValueLabel: 'name'
                             },
                            ]
            };
```

Comment: how are you using/invoking it?

Comment: with uiGrid in columnDef cellFilter for dropdown

Comment: here is an example of how to correctly add a filter.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842194/angularjs-load-html-entity-as-currency-symbol-from-scope/25842874#25842874

you'll need to use the `ng-bind-html` angular attribute

Comment: if you post an example of how you implemented in your filter in markup it would help a lot

Comment: I just added How I am using it in grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http` returns a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) not data.

Ideally a .filter should **never** access any API asynchronously. This is the job for a service.

```
.service('mapMedicineService', ['$http', function($http) {
    this.getMapMedecine = function(input) {
        var map = $http.get('API'+input).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return map;
    }
}]);
```

Then you can retrieve the data from anywhere you want and pass it to your grid:

```
mapMedecineService.getMapMedecine('123').then(function(result) {
    $scope.myData = result;
});
```