# How to display infinity symbol in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to conditionally display a value or an infinity symbol in my Web Page.

I wanted to do something like this ..

```
<td class="rs-table-text" ng-if="batch.est_completion_time ">{{batch.est_completion_time}}</td>
```

That is `if batch.est_completion_time is not empty then display whatever is coming from json`.

And the `json` looks like :

```
{
  "batch_queue_name": "Batch Five",
  "start_date": "05/01/2017 12:18 A.M.",
  "end_date": "08/01/2017 03:37 A.M.",
  "est_completion_time":"&infin;",
  "completion_status": "42"
}
```

But `it does not display the infinity symbol. Rather , it displays the &infin; text only.`

How to achieve the same ?

Comment: So what you want is to make it evaluate HTML entities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML Entities within Angular strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919533/using-html-entities-within-angular-strings)

Comment: use `ng-bind-html="batch.est_completion_time"`

Comment: I feel like rather than sending HTML in your JSON response, you should just send something like `-1` or `infinity` and have a conditional in your Angular template that decides whether or not to display the symbol. Keep the presentational logic in the frontend, not in your API.

Comment: @JoeClay That's a superb advice. I will implement the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, prepare the data as following :

```
$scope.est_completion_time = $sce.trustAsHtml(batch.est_completion_time);
```

In your HTML, you can display it as it is. Don't forget to add `ng-bind-html` in the outer DOM element.

Adding only `ng-bind-html` can do the job :

```
ng-bind-html="batch.est_completion_time"
```

Comment: What is this `$sce` ? Do I need to include any dependency ?

Comment: Yes it has to be injected.